# Saving location information of a video using UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: iphone, location, assetslibrary

I have a video recording app. I sync the recorded videos to the iPhone Camera Roll using UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum. However when I read the synched videos from the Camera Roll using AssetsLibrary framework and access the location information using valueForProperty: ALAssetPropertyLocation API, I do not get valid location.  How do I save the location when I sync the video?

Thanks,
Sahana

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no officially supported way to do this. What you may do: Store the info you want to save in a seperate database. The downside however is that such information is then only available in your app.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Cheers,

Hendrik